# How can I obtain Office 2013 through the 2010 Trial version?

Tags: microsoft-office

My computer came with the not yet bought Microsoft Office 2010 version, how can I update the package so I can then purchase the new version? I didn't see a button.

Comment: Office 2010 and Office 2013 are entirely separate products.  As for doing an update on Office 2010 use Windows Update for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your going to buy office 2013... then just uninstall office 2010.  If you don't 2013 and 2010 with both exist on your computer.

Comment: I didn't buy the 2010 yet.

Comment: Right.  same advice tho, the trial version of 2010 that came pre-installed will not upgrade.  If you plan on buying 2013 (I would) then just uninstall 2010 from the control panel.